# Need to return a row of each ID randomly from a table which has duplicate IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, row

My table has duplicate IDs, so i wanted to return a row of each ID from table which has duplicate IDs.
need help, Thanks in advance.

Example :

```
ID   | NAME  |CODE
-----------------
101  | XXX   | A
101  | XXX   | B
101  | XXX   | C
102  | XXX   | A
102  | XXX   | B
103  | XXX   | A
103  | XXX   | C
104  | XXX   | C
104  | XXX   | C
104  | XXX   | A
104  | XXX   | B
```

I need to return only one ID, from above table so expected output would be..

```
ID   | NAME  |CODE
-----------------
101  | XXX   | A
102  | XXX   | B
103  | XXX   | B
104  | XXX   | A
```

for example i took only four columns here, but in my database my table has 30 to 40 rows.

Comment: Title says "return one ID randomly", but then you want to "return a row of each ID" etc... Contradiction!

Comment: Thanks @jarlh , just updated my title now.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result to make things clearer. (Formatted text please, not images.) And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh updated question now again with some sample data. please look into this.

Answer (score 0):

This will give a list of `id`s along with the number of rows with that `id` for all `id`s that have multiples.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) 
FROM users
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: Can u plz help me now?

Comment: it mereley returns the number of duplicates not the ids. Also please try to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your id is `not null` and `unique`, you may use the following sql to get the desired rows :

```
select * -- to get the complete row
  from myTable
 where id in
            (
             select id
               from myTable
              group by id
             having count(1)>1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give a list of `id`s along with the number of rows with that `id` for all `id`s that have multiples.

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) 
FROM users
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation around your solution rather than just dumping code?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, count(ID) from My_Table
Group by ID 
having count(ID)>1
```

this query allows you to select all the IDs that appear more than once in the table My_Table

Comment: No, i need to return one row from each id.